# How to fix customer register bug on install of SUPPEE-5994 Patch in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-5994

I have installed **SUPPEE-5994 patch in magento 1.9.1.0** and facing customer registration problem.
Initially I discovered that form key is missing, that I fixed. But my problem was not solved.

I debugged the code `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controller/AccountController.php` `createpostAction` function and it was going into catch and giving error **"Cannot save the customer."**

Comment: Magento CE 1.9.2.0 update have solved the problem, so update to 1.9.2

Comment: are you getting password mismatch issue?

Comment: please check the form_key parameter is exist or not in the customer registration form

Comment: @murtaza : I have fixed the password mismatch issue.

Comment: @Ch037 yesterday : Already added form key in register.phtml

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar : ok Thanks... I also got same solution suggestion . Hope it will work.